# Internet not working on my Samsung Galaxy S i9000

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, connection-issues, internet

Recently, my Samsung Galaxy S i9000 will not let me go on FB, Twitter, or anything that requires Internet. It will also not let me download anything from the Market.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using mobile data or Wifi? Have you tried different access points/Wifi networks? Have you verified you APNs?

Answer (score 0):

Check the internet connectivity in status bar (top bar), if alphabet 'E' is displayed, then internet connectivity is fine otherwise contact your service provider for activating EDGE/GPRS services.

If alphabet 'E' is displayed and internet doesn't work, then turn off your mobile, take out the SIM and reinsert it after 10-12 seconds. Turn on the mobile and check. Now internet connectivity should be restored.